# Change content of another element on hover, dynamically in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, hover

I know there are answers out there showing how to use java script/jquery etc to achieve the titled behavior statically. The problem arises when I don't always have the exact id of the element.Since, I m dynamically making a table from the posts(posts from wordpress, but this question doesn't address any plugin or wordpress related query whatsoever, I did this little gig myself without some special pluginor help from wordpress other than posts themselves).

So now what I did is [This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ifFl.png)
I made a table and called table columns using html n php while extracting data from posts.

What I want to do is, whenever I hover on view details, owner name and owner contact should change value from another string I have.

Now, my question here is I can't give unique id to each element, so I can't use the normal id based jquery and set hover actions to get my task done.I thought of using css selectors ( + , ~ , > etc) but I was unable to change content using style's content property.So if any optimal solution to this problem exists, that'd be very helpful.
Thanks in advance & Regards.

My code(If needed at all) -

```html
<?php
$string = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'property_owner_name',true);
 $tring = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'property_owner_alternate_contact',true);
 $fring=substr($tring, 0, -5)."XXXXXXXXXX"; 

 $owner_name;
 $owner_contact;
 if((current_user_can('editor')||current_user_can('administrator')))
$owner_name =   $string;
else
$owner_name ='XXXXXX'; // String to change to
 
  if((current_user_can('editor')||current_user_can('administrator')))
$owner_contact =   $fring;
else
$owner_contact =substr($fring,0,10);  //String to change to
 
?>


 
<tr>
    
<td class="text-left"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_location( $post->ID );   ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_status( $post->ID );   ?></td>

<td class="text-left hide2"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_types( $post->ID ); ?></td>

<td class="text-left hide1"><?php the_title(); ?></td>

<td class="text-left hide3" id="a">XXXXXX</td>

<td class="text-left hide3" id="b"> XXXXXXXXXX</td>

<td class="text-right"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn real-btn"style="background:#68cfef; color:#fff; min-width:115px;" >VIEW DETAILS</a></td>

</tr>
```

Update (Codes of file actually calling this template in a loop ) :

```html
<div id="home-properties" class="property-items-container clearfix">
                                    <?php
                                    /* List of Properties on Homepage */
                                    $number_of_properties = intval( get_option('theme_properties_on_home') );
                                    if(!$number_of_properties){
                                        $number_of_properties = 4;
                                    }

                                    if ( is_front_page()  ) {
                                        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
                                    }

                                    $home_args = array(
                                        'post_type' => 'property',
                                        'posts_per_page' => $number_of_properties,
                                        'paged' => $paged
                                    );

                                    /* Modify home query arguments based on theme options - related filters resides in functions.php */
                                    $home_args = apply_filters( 'real_homes_homepage_properties', $home_args );

                                    /* Sort Properties Based on Theme Option Selection */
                                    $sorty_by = get_option('theme_sorty_by');
                                    if ( ! empty( $sorty_by ) ) {
                                        if ( $sorty_by == 'low-to-high' ) {
                                            $home_args[ 'orderby' ]  = 'meta_value_num';
                                            $home_args[ 'meta_key' ] = 'REAL_HOMES_property_price';
                                            $home_args[ 'order' ]    = 'ASC';
                                        } elseif ( $sorty_by == 'high-to-low' ) {
                                            $home_args[ 'orderby' ]  = 'meta_value_num';
                                            $home_args[ 'meta_key' ] = 'REAL_HOMES_property_price';
                                            $home_args[ 'order' ]    = 'DESC';
                                        } elseif ( $sorty_by == 'random' ) {
                                            $home_args[ 'orderby' ] = 'rand';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $home_properties_query = new WP_Query( $home_args );

                                    /* Homepage Properties Loop */
                                    if ( $home_properties_query->have_posts() ) :

                                        $post_count = 0;?>
           
          <table  width=100% id="design2" class="table-fill" border=0>
          
          <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Location</th>
          <th class="text-center">Status</th>
          <th class="text-center hide2">Type</th>
          <th class="text-center hide1">Description</th>
          <th class="text-center hide3">Owner's Name</th>
          <th class="text-center hide3">Owner's Number</th>
          <th class="text-center"></th>
          </tr>
          <tbody class="table-hover">
          <?php
                                        while ( $home_properties_query->have_posts() ) :

                                            $home_properties_query->the_post();

                                            /* Display Property for Home Page */
                                            get_template_part('template-parts/property-for-home');

                                            /* To output clearfix after every 2 properties */
                                            $post_count++;                                       
                                                /*echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';*/
                                          
           ?>
           <?php

                                        endwhile;
          echo '<tbody></table>';

                                    else:
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="alert-wrapper">
                                            <h4><?php _e('No Properties Found!', 'framework') ?></h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                    ?>

                                </div>
```

Yup its frm a theme I bought and they dnt support customization obviously. Actually I had already tried using jquery giving the columns i need an id which changes based on **$post_count** like 'a1' 'a2' 'a3', 'b1' 'b2' 'b3' etc but I dont really know where I messed it up in jquery( I hacked some examples into my code from stackoverflow ), put them in the looping template and console was giving me some 'uncaughtreferenceerrors' & some other things next time(new at java n stuff)(In overall, i couldn't hack it in correctly). So, if u guyz cn come up with some stuff I could use that'd be very helpful...doesn't matter if its done by css, js or wtevr.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: First of all, PHP can't do anything in the page itself once it's loaded by the browser. The browser doesn't run PHP code. For any meaningful help, you will need to provide more code. Specifically, the code you show appears to handle a single row of the table. What calls it? Is it inside a loop? If the later is true, you could give each row a unique id simply by counting the rows and using 1, 2, 3, etc. That would be enough for JS to at least identify the row in the table.

Comment: Also, with jQuery you can use $(this) in the function called by the hover event, and pull info from other parts of the same row. data- attributes for example.

Comment: could you please frame an example code of that, so I can give it a shot without messing up things u ask me to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the Javascript that you are using for the on hover event? What needs to change during the on hover? Too much missing info to provide anything meaningful.

Comment: I never originally had any hover event pre-setup just trying to do it all frm scratch.....Srry for being unable to provide more stuff but this is all the code that the table I made currently uses any new hover or stuff is yet to be made(I tried but failed with some errors in chrome's console so removed it). It would be very helpful if something can be done about it. Thanks anyway fr at least engaging with the question & fr any future help.

Comment: So, answer the other two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done using Post id as unique element and was having problems because wordpress doesn't use '$' in js,instead use 'jquery' term for doing work.Thanks fr looking into the question anyway.Here's my edited template code, If ever required in future.

```html
<?php
$string = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'inspiry_property_owner_name',true);
 $tring = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'inspiry_property_owner_alternate_contact',true);
 $fring=substr($tring, 0, -5)."XXXXXXXXXX"; 

 $owner_name;
 $owner_contact;
 if((current_user_can('editor')||current_user_can('administrator')))
$owner_name =   $string;
else
$owner_name ='XXXXXX';
 
  if((current_user_can('editor')||current_user_can('administrator')))
$owner_contact =   $fring;
else
$owner_contact =substr($fring,0,10);
 

  $id = get_the_ID();
 $uniqueid = 'infohide'.$id;
 $uniqueidz = 'infounhide'.$id; 
  
 ?>
 
 <style>
.<?php echo $uniqueidz; ?>{
 display:none;
}
</style>

    <tr>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_location( $post->ID );   ?></td>
<td class="text-left"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_status( $post->ID );   ?></td>
<td class="text-left hide2"><?php echo inspiry_get_property_types( $post->ID ); ?></td>
<td class="text-left hide1"><?php the_title(); ?></td>
  
  
<td class="text-left hide3" >
<div class="<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>">XXXXXX</div>
<div class="<?php echo $uniqueidz; ?>"> <?php echo $owner_name; ?></div>
</td>


<td class="text-left hide3" >
<div class="<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>">XXXXXXXXXX </div>
<div class="<?php echo $uniqueidz; ?>"> <?php echo $owner_contact; ?></div>
</td>


<td class="text-right">

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn real-btn"style="background:#68cfef; color:#fff; min-width:115px;" onmouseover="bigImg<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>()" onmouseout="normalImg<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>()">VIEW DETAILS</a>
</td>



<!--td><?php /*$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('get_post_meta');
print $reflFunc->getFileName() . ':' . $reflFunc->getStartLine(); */ ?> </td-->
  

  <script>
  function bigImg<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>() {
  jQuery('.<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.<?php echo $uniqueidz; ?>').css('display', 'block');
      
}
function normalImg<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>() {
  jQuery('.<?php echo $uniqueidz; ?>').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('.<?php echo $uniqueid; ?>').css('display', 'block');
}


  
  </script>
        
        
          </tr>
```